# Spring RestController not displaying html page, just text

Tags: java, spring, rest

WebPageController.java

```
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class WebPageController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "templates/index.html";
}

@GetMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "greeting";
}
```

}

pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>sean</groupId>
<artifactId>slynchnet</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>slynchnet</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

trying to load this webpage.

index.html

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <p>Get your greeting<a href="/greeting">here</a></p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

However all that is returned is the text, index.html is not being displayed by the web browser, i added all the dependencies I thought i would need. The tomcat server runs fine and there is no warnings anywhere to indicate I need to add something.

Comment: What exactly is displayed?

Comment: Please use `@Controller `not `@RestController`

Comment: What is returned is "index" for localhost:8080/ and "greeting" for localhost:8080/greeting

Answer (score -1):

Your browser is not displaying it as a html document, because it doesn't recognize it as such. Please read about the HTML5 standard and it's minimal requirements, eg. [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-minimal-html-document-html5-edition/)